# pycrypto: unable to decrypt file

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, pycrypto

I am using PKCS1_OAEP crypto algorithm to encrypt a file. The file is encrypted successfully but unable to decrypt file, getting the error "Ciphertext with incorrect length."

Encryption Algorithm is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import zlib
import base64


fd = open('test.doc', 'rb')
message = fd.read()
fd.close()

print "[*] Original File Size: %d" % len(message)

#message = 'To be encrypted'
key = RSA.importKey(open('pubkey.der').read())
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

compressed = zlib.compress(message)
print "[*] Compressed File Size: %d" % len(compressed)

chunk_size = 128

ciphertext = ""
offset = 0

while offset < len(compressed):
    chunk = compressed[offset:offset+chunk_size]

    if len(chunk) % chunk_size != 0:
        chunk += " " * (chunk_size - len(chunk)) # Padding with spaces

    ciphertext += cipher.encrypt(chunk)
    offset += chunk_size

print "[*] Encrypted File Size: %d" % len(ciphertext)

encoded = ciphertext.encode("base64")

print "[*] Encoded file size: %d" % len(encoded)

fd = open("enc.data", 'wb')
fd.write(encoded)
fd.close()

print "[+] File saved successfully!"
```

Decryption Algorithm is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import zlib
import base64

key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.der').read())
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

fd = open('enc.data', 'rb')
encoded = fd.read().strip('\n')
fd.close()

decoded = encoded.decode("base64")


chunk_size = 128
offset = 0
plaintext = ""

while offset < len(decoded):
    plaintext += cipher.decrypt(decoded[offset:offset+chunk_size])
    offset += chunk_size

#plaintext = cipher.decrypt(decoded)

decompress = zlib.decompress(plaintext)


fd = open('decr.doc', 'wb')
fd.write(decompress)
fd.close()
```

Using the following script to generate key

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 

new_key = RSA.generate(2048, e=65537) 
public_key = new_key.publickey().exportKey("PEM") 
private_key = new_key.exportKey("PEM") 


fileWrite(fileName, data):
    fd = open(fileName, 'wb')
    fd.write(data)
    fd.close()

fileWrite('privkey.der', private_key)
fileWrite('pubkey.der', public_key)
```

[Here is the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY8ox.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encrypt with a **2048 bit RSA key**, which gives encrypted blocks of **2048 bites (256 bytes)**. Your decrypt implementation assumes the encrypted blocks are **128 bytes** where they are actually **256 bytes**, and thus you get the 'incorrect length' error. Notice how your encrypted files size (64512) is more than double of the compressed file size (32223).

In general you would not use **RSA** for **bulk encryption** (as it's quite slow) but would instead combine it with a symmetric encryption like **AES**. You would then encrypt the data with a random **AES** key, and then encrypt the **AES** key with the **RSA** key. This way you get the speed of **AES** and the two keys of **RSA**. This is known as [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Thanks for your awesome suggestion, I will try it later but now for learning purposes I am using RSA to encrypt data.

I have changed the chunk size to 256 and the file size I want to encrypt is 21 bytes. Now I am getting "Plaintext is too long" error. [link] (http://imgur.com/a/VKiFi)

Comment: The output of each encryption is 256 bytes, but the input (with the OAEP padding you use) can maximum be 214 bytes. So you would need different chunk size for input & output.

Comment: Thank you sir :) @Ebbe M.Pederse